# Uncaught TypeError: passwordInput.search is not a function

Tags: javascript

Trying to validate username and password but i get an error even when the username and password are correct. I get a `TypeError`, what I'm I doing wrong? Is the String method I'm using ?

```
function validateLogin() {
    let passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
    let userName = document.getElementById('userName');

    event.preventDefault();

    // Set errors to an empty array
    let errors = [];

    // Conditions for password validation   

    if(passwordInput.length < 8) {
        errors.push('Your password must be at least 8 characters long')
    }
    if(passwordInput.search(/[a-z]/) < 0) {
        errors.push('Your password must cotain at least one lowercase letter')
    }
    if(passwordInput.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
        errors.push('Your password must conatin at least one uppercase letter')
    }
    if(passwordInput.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
        errors.push('Password must contain at least one number!')
    }
    if(passwordInput.search(/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\.\,\;\:\-]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one special character.")
    }

    // Login
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = errors.join("<br>")
        console.log('Error logging in')
        return false;
    } else if(errors.length < 0 && userName.value){
        console.log('Youre logged in!')
    }
};
```

Comment: What's your question? What issues are you having? What's the issue with the code provided? Does `passwordInput` ever get updated?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: Update the values of `userName` and `passwordInput` in your validation function. They seem to be defined globally and do not get updated (_ex: always getting to be an empty string_)

Comment: Your errors can be found in the } else if(!errors && userName.value){ line. First of all, !errors will always be false, because even an empty array is truey. Second, userName is a string and has no value, so that's undefined and will be falsy. You just need to check whether userName is truey, like } else if (userName) {

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `TypeError` on `search` because `search` is a function of `String`, and you are using it in context of `element`.

All you need to do is to use the `value` of the `passwordInput` and it should be fine.

Instead of using:

```
let passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
```

Which is of type `element`.

You should use:

```
let passwordInput = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Of type `String`.

Now you should be able to use `passwordInput.search` because `passwordInput` is a String and `search` is a string function.

Comment: Doing that the function doesn't run

Comment: @AlexUdose which function? what's not working? give more information if you want to solve your problem. Since you didn't add the entire code we can't know what's not working.

Comment: The validate function doesn't run